# Sorting questions..

Tags: java, sorting, netbeans-6.9

Hello there I'm new to programming and I'm currently tasked to create a program relating to Sorting. and I keep getting the error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
       at sorting.Sorting.main(Sorting.java:17)
 Java Result: 1
```

The line it tells where the error is line 17 which contains:

```
 if (ArrayOfInts[j] > ArrayOfInts[j + 1])
```

please help.. heres the whole thing.

```
public class Sorting{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       int[] ArrayOfInts = {42, 97, 3, 689, 14, 1076, 3000, 8, 632, 327, 976, 4215};
       for(int i = ArrayOfInts.length; i >= 1; i--){
          for(int j = 0; j < i; j--){
            if (ArrayOfInts[j] > ArrayOfInts[j + 1]){
                int temp = ArrayOfInts[j];
                ArrayOfInts[j] = ArrayOfInts[j + 1];
                ArrayOfInts[j - 1] = temp;

            }
          }
       }
       for(int i = 0; i < ArrayOfInts.length; i++){
            System.out.println(ArrayOfInts[i] + " ");
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well the message itself suggests your logic of `j + 1` is causing the array to go out of bounds. Index starts from 0 to length - 1.

Answer (score 2):

When `j=0`, this line is problematic:

```
ArrayOfInts[j - 1] = temp;
```

as you try to access -1 index in an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = ArrayOfInts.length; i >= 1; i--)
```

Hi please replace above code line with below line

```
for(int i = ArrayOfInts.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made few correction to the code:
1. for 1st for loop, instead of int i = ArrayOfInts.length, use int i = ArrayOfInts.length-1, this is beacuse, length will return number of elements in array, and array is zero indexed hence in your case length will be 12 i.e. 0 to 11.
2.For 2nd for loop, instead of j- use j++ because j is starting from 0 to i.
3.instead of  ArrayOfInts[j - 1] = temp; use  ArrayOfInts[j + 1] = temp;

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] ArrayOfInts = {42, 97, 3, 689, 14, 1076, 3000, 8, 632, 327, 976, 4215};
        for(int i = ArrayOfInts.length-1; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (ArrayOfInts[j] > ArrayOfInts[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = ArrayOfInts[j];
                    ArrayOfInts[j] = ArrayOfInts[j + 1];
                    ArrayOfInts[j + 1] = temp;

                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < ArrayOfInts.length; i++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(ArrayOfInts[i] + " ");
                        System.out.println();
                    }
    }
```